# No se envia email con archivo usando phpmailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Quiero enviar un email, con un archivo .xls pero no se por que motivo no se manda, ya que no aparece error alguno. Solo muestra el mensaje de que ha ocurrido un error al enviar que añadí yo para controlar si se envia o no. El código es el siguiente:

```
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    require 'PHPMailer-master/src/Exception.php';


    require 'PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php';
    require 'PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->Username = $email;
    $mail->Password = $pass;

    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Host = $host;
    $mail->Port = 25;
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // use SMTP
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SetFrom = ($mail->Username."Remitente");
    $mail->AddAddress($destinatario);
    $mail->Subject = "Demo de PHPMailer";
    $mail->Body = "Hola, esto es una demo de envio de emails con archivos adjuntos!!!";

    $file_to_attach = 'C:\Users\Lorenzo\xampp\htdocs\Devoluciones\Devoluciones.xls';
    $mail->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach, "Devoluciones.xls");

    if($mail->Send()){
        echo '<p>Se ha enviado correctamente el email </p>';
    }else{
        echo "<p>Error al enviar el email {$mail->ErrorInfo}</p>";
    }
```

Se ha actualizado el código con los último cambios sugeridos en la respuesta. El error que lanza ahora mismo es el siguiente:

```
Error al enviar el email Invalid address: (From): root@localhost
```

Comment: Lo primero, no te muestra error, por que no estas mostrando la excepcion, asi que esta normal. Quieres añadir un archivo a tu email, pero no estas adjuntando nada a este, ya que el primer parametro es el archivo y el segundo el nombre. Pero el archivo no te lo irá a buscar a la ruta especificada, debes pasarle el archivo como tal.

Comment: Por algún motivo, tu servidor no permite enviar desde from root@localhost, trata de corregir eso o añadir un from correcto a phpmailer.

Comment: OJO, esto es un método, no es una variable, tienes que ponerlo así: `$mail->setFrom($mail->Username,"Remitente");` **sin el signo de `=`**

Answer (score 0):

Si es un archivo local PHPMailer te permite enviarlo como adjunto sin complicaciones, lo único es que en la ruta tienes que poner la ruta local, no la URL, tal y como advierte [la documentación (traducción)](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Tutorial):

> ... Tenga en cuenta que no puede usar una URL para la ruta; solo puede
>   usar la ruta del sistema de archivos local. Consulte las notas sobre
>   los archivos adjuntos de cadenas a continuación para saber cómo usar
>   contenido remoto.
>
> La ruta puede ser relativa (desde su script, no la clase PHPMailer) o
>   una ruta completa al archivo que desea adjuntar. Si desea enviar
>   contenido desde una base de datos o API web (por ejemplo, un generador
>   de PDF remoto), no use este método; use `addStringAttachment` en su
>   lugar.

Atendiendo a eso, en tu archivo falta la ruta completa, porque no estás poniendo en ella el nombre del archivo.

Si asumimos que el archivo se llama `Devoluciones.xls`, así debería funcionar:

```
#Nótese que hemos agregado el nombre del archivo
$file_to_attach = 'C:\Users\Lorenzo\xampp\htdocs\Devoluciones\Devoluciones.xls';
$mail->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach, "Devoluciones.xls",);

if($mail->Send()){
    echo '<p>Se ha enviado correctamente el email </p>';
}else{
    #Agregamos información sobre un posible error
    echo "<p>Error al enviar el email: {$mail->ErrorInfo}</p>";
}
```

Tienes error también en esta línea:

```
$mail->SetFrom = ($mail->Username."Remitente");
```

`setFrom` es un método, no es una variable que hay que igualar. Además, la palabra `Remitente` sería el segundo parámetro que le pasas al método, ahí lo que haces es concatenar con el punto.

Corregido quedaría así:

```
$mail->setFrom($mail->Username,"Remitente");
```

Comment: He añadido lo sugerido y continua sin enviar. El error devuelto es Error al enviar el email Invalid address: (From): root@localhost supongo que es error del usuario de envio

Comment: @Lorenzo revisa esta línea: `$mail->SetFrom = ($mail->Username."Remitente");` no creo que eso produzca un email válido. ¿No basta con poner `$mail->SetFrom = ($mail->Username);` ? si es que `$mail->Username` tiene la dirección correcta. Puedes verificarlo poniendo un `var_dump($mail->Username);` o poniendo una dirección a mano para probar.

Comment: He imprimido el valor y muestra el email introducido en la variable, tambien he probado a ponerlo a mano, pero sigue el mismo error.

Comment: @Lorenzo revisa [el ejemplo de la documentación](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Tutorial#first-time), y usa los métodos con la convención estándar: `addAttacehment(), setFrom(), send()` etc. Si no funciona edita la pregunta poniendo el código actual cuando hayas rectificado al modo indicado en el enlace.